# XPath to extract text from two out of many nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to extract text from two out of many nodes. Having the following XML:

```
<nodes>
    <first>1</first>
    <second>2</second>
    <third>3</third>
</nodes>
```

I want to extract just text from `first` and `second` nodes to have result `12`. How can I do that?

The query `concat(/nodes/first/text(), /nodes/second/text())` works for me, but I'm looking for something more generic and without duplication of `/nodes` part.

Comment: Why this question was downvoted? Please provide a reason, I can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This would depend a lot on your implementation.  Using xpath 1, the way that you have selected would be the only thing that will work (other than using an implementation for which you can write extension functions).  XPath 1 can not handle this on its own.

However, we can select all of the relevant nodes using

```
/nodes/*[local-name()='first' or local-name()='second']
```

or

```
/nodes/*[self::first or self::second]
```

or if you want a range of positions, we can simplify this to

```
/nodes/*[position()<3]
```

and then use our implementation to do the concatenation.

For example, with XSLT, I might do

```
<xsl:for-each select="/nodes/*[position()&lt;3]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

or using an xpath function in a programming language, we could iterate over the result and concatenate it.  For example, with python and the lxml library (where root is an lxml.etree object holding the document), we could do (using the position based selector)

```
"".join(root.xpath("/nodes/*[position()<3]/text()"))
```

---

Using xpath 2, this is possible directly with

```
string-join(/nodes/*[position()<3],'')
```

In fact, if we need to select by name, xpath 2 allows us to simplify the first xpath expression listed, and do

```
string-join(/nodes/*[local-name()=('first','second')])
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid post-processing using XPath 2.0?

Comment: @MichalKordas What do you mean by "post-processing"?  If you mean only using xpath 2, the expression at the end of my post will just select a value of '12' as you requested.  No need for the implementation to do any extra work - the xpath engine does all of the work.  It is only xpath 1 that has this limitation.  Unfortunately, xpath 2 tools are far rarer.

Comment: Yes, I meant using just XPath, no other tools. BTW, my nodes can be anywhere and they are not ordered so I can't use `position()`

Comment: @MichalKordas Then use something like `/nodes/*[self:first or self::second]` or (in xpath 2) even something like `/nodes/*[local-name()= ('first','second')]`.  If the nodes can be at any position, you can use `/nodes//*[local-name()=('first','second')]` or `/nodes//*[self:first or self:second]` or any variation.